# Is it possible to specify a custom Dockerfile for docker run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have searched high and low for an answer to this question. Perhaps it's not possible!

I have some `Dockerfile`s in directories such as `dev/Dockerfile` and `live/Dockerfile`. I cannot find a way to provide these custom `Dockerfile`s to `docker run`. `docker build` has the `-f` option, but I cannot find a corresponding option for `docker run` in the root of the app. At the moment I think I will write my `npm`/`gulp` script to simply change into those directories, but this is clearly not ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: But `docker run` takes images as arguments not Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - that's not how Docker works:

- The Dockerfile is used with `docker build` to build an *image*
- The resulting *image* is used with `docker run` to run a *container*

If you need to make changes at run-time, then you need to modify your base image so that it can take, e.g. a command-line option to `docker run`, or a configuration file as a mount.